# How to select only duplicates in a chart in r

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm analyzing a df and I need to isolate the duplicates. Way boiled down it looks like this:

| Name | School | Favorite Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Billy | ND | Green |
| Joey | Michigan | Blue |
| Tina | BC | Gold |
| John | BC | Red |
| Shaun | Michigan | Teal |

I need to take only the schools that have more than person there.

I've gotten so far as dupilicate_schools <- duplicated(school_color_list$School) which gives me a vector showing the matches but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Have you tried `df %>% group_by(School) %>% filter(n()>1)`?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: desired output would be the bottom four entries on the df

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with the `data.table` package based on the `duplicated()` function as you wish. Please, find the reprex below.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, `:=` (Duplicates_1 = duplicated(df1, by = "School"), Duplicates_2 = duplicated(df1, by = "School", fromLast = TRUE))
           ][Duplicates_1 == TRUE | Duplicates_2 == TRUE
             ][, `:=` (Duplicates_1 = NULL, Duplicates_2 = NULL)][]
```

- Ouput

```r
#>     Name   School Favorite_Color
#> 1:  Joey Michigan           Blue
#> 2:  Tina       BC           Gold
#> 3:  John       BC            Red
#> 4: Shaun Michigan           Teal
```

- Data

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Billy", "Joey", "Tina", "John", "Shaun"),
                  School = c("ND", "Michigan", "BC", "BC", "Michigan"),
                  Favorite_Color = c("Green", "Blue", "Gold", "Red", "Teal"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>